# quantiles with convex combination

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, quantile, quantile-function

I have define the right quantile and left quantile, and I want to study the quantiles with convex combination. that's $$F^{-1}(q) = \inf\{x: F(x) \geq q\},$$ and $$F^{-1+}(q) = \inf\{x: F(x) > q\}.$$
is there some paper to study the following form quantile: $$F^{-1, \lambda}(q) = (1 - \lambda) F^{-1}(q) + \lambda F^{-1+}(q), \forall \lambda \in [0, 1].$$

Comment: Aren't those infimums, as written, equal, since presumably the cdf $F$ is continuous and the first set is the closure of the second?

Comment: For a distribution with a flat part, the left and right quantiles must be unequal.

Comment: Oh, I was assuming the p.d.f had support cross the whole domain of $q$. So, there are gaps in the p.d.f, and thus stretches where the c.d.f $F(x)$ constant. And this is an analytic c.d.f, and not empirical one, correct?